# Module endomorphisms of simple modules where they do not commute by composition.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an example of module homomorphisms $f,g : M\to M$ where $M$ is a simple $R$-module such that $f\circ g \ne g\circ f$ ?

Comment: Depending on what *exactly* $\;R\;$ is (commutative, integral domain, Noetherian, Euclidean, etc.), the answer may be pretty similar to the one already given for the case of simple abelian groups.

Comment: What would be the $R$ for such example to exist?

Comment: @Joanpemo Since image of an endomorphism is a submodule, endomorphism could really be $0 :M \to M$ and a bijective function not necessarily an identity. Then $0:M\to M$ would commute with any endomorphism, but would there be 2 bijective functions $f,g$ such that they do not commute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Schur's lemma, the endomorphism ring of a simple module is a division ring. Every division ring (including noncommutative ones like the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$) appears: namely, every division ring $D$ is the endomorphism ring of $D$ as a right $D$-module (which is simple).

One setting where noncommutative division rings naturally appear as endomorphisms is in representation theory: in general, the endomorphism ring of an irreducible representation of a group $G$ over a field $k$ is a division algebra over $k$, not necessarily commutative. For example, when $k = \mathbb{R}$, all three division algebras $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}$ appear. This is closely related to the notion of [Frobenius-Schur indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator).